# How to make two requests one right after the other using OkHttp

Tags: android, okhttp

I know in volley there's a queue I can use to have a request run after the other, but how can I do this with OKHTTP?

Some context: I'm doing a project which takes data from an API and displays on the phone. But the API has many different URLs and I need to use 2 of them to get all the data that I want. Do I need have multiple uses of OkHTTP or can I use the same one for everything.

Comment: Use sync API with own background thread/AsyncTask/etc. ...

Comment: Do you have a good tutorial?

Comment: @user2426691 you can check the [Official docs](https://github.com/square/okhttp/wiki/Recipes) for examples using synchronous requests

Answer (score 0):

If there are only small differences between the URLs, you can create a method that makes the OKHTTP call that has the "different" part of each URL as the parameter, which you can then fill in that part of the URL.

Then all you'd have to do is call that method 3 times with the different parameters